# Mocking class primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I've got a piece of code that was in the project before I came onboard :

```
def create_message!
  Message.create(
        :sender_id => @sending_user.id,
        :receiver_id => recipient_user.id,
        :body => @body,
        :read => false
      )
end
```

We recently added publicactivity gem to our projects so I modified the code :

```
def create_message!
    message =  Message.create(
            :sender_id => @sending_user.id,
            :receiver_id => recipient_user.id,
            :body => @body,
            :read => false
          )

    message.create_activity :create, owner: @sending_user, recipient: recipient_user
    message 
    end
```

But now the test fails :

```
1) MandrillEvent parses inbound responses
     Failure/Error: message = MandrillEvent.process(@msgs[0])
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `primary_key' for RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class
     # ./app/models/mandrill_event.rb:59:in `create_message!'
     # ./app/models/mandrill_event.rb:93:in `process'
     # ./spec/models/mandrill_event_spec.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my test :

```
describe MandrillEvent do
  before do
    MyApp::Application.stub_chain(:config, :mandrill_email_domain).and_return('example.com')
    json = File.read 'spec/support/assets/mandrill_inbound.json'
    @msgs = JSON.parse json

    sending_user = double("User")
    sending_user.stub(:id) { 1 }
    receiving_user = double("User")
    receiving_user.stub(:id) { 2 }
    User.stub(:find_by_email) { sending_user }
    match = double("Match")
    match.stub(:id) { 1 }
    match.stub(:involves?){ true }
    match.stub(:other_user){ receiving_user }
    Match.stub(:find_by_uuid) { match }
    Message.any_instance.stub(:send_notification)
  end

  describe MandrillEvent::EmailMessage do
    subject { MandrillEvent::EmailMessage.new(@msgs[0]['msg']) }

    it { should respond_to(:body) }
    it { should respond_to(:from) }
    it { should respond_to(:sending_user) }
    it { should respond_to(:matched?) }

    it 'checks matches' do
      subject.matched?.should be_true
    end
  end

  it 'parses inbound responses' do
    message = MandrillEvent.process(@msgs[0])
    message.should_not be_nil
    message.body.should_not be_nil
  end
```

How does my code change cause this error :

```
undefined method `primary_key' for RSpec::Mocks::Mock:Class
```

What amendments to the test should I make? Why does the test look for primary_key column?

Comment: This could be useful https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this error occurs when you call `message.create_activity` and pass the owner `double("User")`.

You can try to either add `primary_key` to the double:

```
sending_user = double("User")
sending_user.stub(:primary_key) { 1 }
# ...
```

or

```
sending_user = double("User", primary_key: 1)
```

Or make your double lenient, by making it a `null_object`:

```
sending_user = double("User").as_null_object
sending_user.stub(:id) { 1 }
```